# HDD test for "SMART Non Supported" drive?

Tags: tools

I'm trying to run a health check on a WD10EZEX on Disk Utility and the smart status reads "not supported". The drive seemed to format just fine but it is a system pull and I wanted it thoroughly tested before I use it. I was able to perform a benchmark test but I'm not sure how to read the results as I'm more familiar with the SMART test results. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can read smart status with `smartmontools`

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
```

and then perform smart read from e.g. sdb drive

```
sudo smartctl -A /dev/sdb
```

or run healthy check

```
sudo smartctl -H /dev/sdb
```